# Why are Unbreakable Vows not used more in the Harry Potter Universe?

Tags: harry-potter, unbreakable-vow

I wonder why the Wizarding Legal System doesn't use Unbreakable Vows in their legal system. Having the judges swear *"to uphold the law to their best ability while acting in their official role"* would really cut down corruption, making it almost impossible to abuse ones position.

Likewise, having accused criminals forced to swear *"to not intentionally commit perjury while before the Wizengamot today, and to vocally correct any mistakes in [accused's] claims when realizing a mistake has been made"*. This would make it a more limiting Vow, as it only lasts for the duration of that particular day, and could be used for any trial about a crime of specific severity.

Most likely, it's not used simply because the Wizarding World is based on, and created from, corruption and power-lust. The very goverment exists more for the sake of being able to obtain power than to create a good country. The members of the Wizengamot **want to** be able to do illegal and immoral acts to further their own power, so they refuse to make laws that might limit their ability to do so (or increase the risk of them geting caught).

Comment: One issue that springs to mind, it could be abused to gather sensitive information. You could have a disposable crony bring a spurious claim against a senior wizard and then effectively have them in court, compelled to truthfully answer your questions, even though they're guilty of nothing. A judge might prevent direct questions of a sensitive nature, but you could creatively work around this, such as alleging a crime on a certain date and then asking them their alibi when you suspect they were meeting with certain persons or doing certain deeds that day, and they would have to confirm it.

Comment: It also results in a sacrifice from every wizard/witch involved with the Vow. (According to HPMOR)

Comment: (According to HPMOR: "The Unbreakable Vow requires three participants and three sacrifices. The one who receives the Unbreakable Vow must be one who could have come to trust the Vower, but chooses instead to demand the Vow from them, and they sacrifice that possibility of trust.")

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath Isn't HPMOR fan fiction....?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Yes, that's why I'm not posting as an answer...

Comment: Several related questions: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/13432/100430 https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/146239/100430 https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/112546/100430 In fact, the third one seems to be essentially the same as yours, so I’ve closed this as a duplicate.

Comment: As the Ministry of Magic is a Ministerial Department of the British Government (evidenced in book 7), it is subject to these pesky things called "presumption of innocence" (i.e. **don't** call The Accused a Criminal... *yet*), and the Declaration of Human Rights (Article 3:  No Torture.  It *also* makes information obtained under duress - such as, for example, "answer the question truthfully, or the unbreakable vow will kill you" - inadmissible in legal proceedings).  Presumably, this is also why Veritaserum is not used either.

Comment: human-folk are capable of doublethink, therefore any such use would not only be useless, but also be abusive.  Do folk swear to uphold the law?  Law is made by human-folk, is manipulable and all of a sudden folk are *required* to commit atrocities by law (ie, legalised -isms and their laws). Do folk swear to do what is right or honorable or just? Not only are there still bigots or terrorists (they *believe* it is right) but others can't accuse them because *most* wouldn't think so, and hey, didn't they swear? Do they swear to tell the truth?  well, they weren't *people* so it wasn't *murder*.

Comment: I understand what 'delinear' means by it being used to gather information on an innocent, but the vow I proposed could not be used for that; it prevents them from lying, it does not compell them to answer. So they would not have to describe what they did that day, just say "I am not guilty of the crime I have been accused of" and that'd be enough.